# How to uninstall ADB drivers from Windows 10?

Tags: adb

If I type "adb devices" to CMD I want it to be unrecognized. Not sure if this question for superuser but it's related to Android. I have installed [this](https://adbdriver.com/downloads/) automated installation, however it's not available now.

Comment: I assume you want all `adb` commands (not only `adb devices`) to be unrecognized by the command prompt. That said, this is unrelated to Android because it is about manipulating Windows 10's PATH environment variable.

Comment: type `where adb` in the shell to see where adb is installed. The drivers can be deinstalled via device manager when enabling the "show hidden devices" option the select "USB devices" node to see the ADB interfaces.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!